# Run 2 threads indefinitly with join

Tags: c++, multithreading

What's the best practice to achieve this :

- 1 - Thread for gathering data
- 2 - Wait for (1) to finish and render data

And those, indefinitely

```
while (true) {
        thread tGatherData(getData); // Get data 
        tGatherData.join();          // Wait for data
        thread tRender(render);      // Render data
        Sleep(3);
}
```

Using it like this doesn't sound like a good practice because it creates a new thread everytime right ?

How should I proceed ? Thanks

Comment: why do you want to use two threads in the first place, when the second thread has to wait for the first to finish always?

Comment: `thread tGatherData(getData); tGatherData.join();` is effectively the same as `getData();` plus the overhead of creating a thread.

Comment: this is not so much about good or bad practice, but your code would outright terminate for not joining `tRender`. And if you do join it your code is purely sequential. Please clarify what you want to do in parallel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to create thread on each iteration of your loop, you may want to start 2 threads: one for gathering information, second for printing it, and place your loop in both threads(you should remember about synchronization)

For example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/4b5EnfdGx) I've created two threads: first for reading from console, second for printing. Synchronization is done by atomic. The program will stop execution, when it reads 0.

But, as good as I understand your code, you don't need second thread at all. All You need is to place your render function inside main thread. And your gathering function isn't asynchronous. It just create another thread and instantly start to wait for it's finishing, so your program should be single thread